# What is the canonical Ruby on Rails question?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Writing these down before we forget. We have a bunch:

- [Best way to Install Ruby 1.9, Rails 3, Postgres, Heroku, GitHub, Using RVM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48984/best-way-to-install-ruby-1-9-rails-3-postgres-heroku-github-using-rvm)
- [How do I set up Ruby on Rails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7654/how-do-i-set-up-ruby-on-rails)
- [Step by step guide to install Ruby on Rails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13541/step-by-step-guide-to-install-ruby-on-rails)
- [How can I easily install ruby on rails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150446/how-can-i-easily-install-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 1):

Status in progress.

I'm working on that today, I just need to understand how the heck to use rbenv. :p

Comment: waiting for ya!

Comment: @green7 I haven't been able to make rbenv work for me. I am offering a bounty on that question soon so we have an answer.